# What happens when typing the "cd" command to a Linux Git directory?

Tags: linux, git, shell

I have a VPS with CentOS system. The system has a high loadavg in normal time.

I have a Git directory which is very large (nearly 800 MB). When I type command `cd` to the directory, it takes so long time of the shell to respond.

What happen when I type `cd` to the Git directory? What can I do to optimize the enter time?

Add my Bash profile here:

This is my `.bash_profile` file:

```
function parse_git_dirty {
    [[ $(git status 2> /dev/null | tail -n1) != "nothing to commit (working directory clean)" ]] && echo "*"
}

function parse_git_branch {
    git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e "s/* \(.*\)/[\1$(parse_git_dirty)]/"
}
export PS1='\u@\h:\w\[\e[1;36m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[0m\]$ '
```

Comment: Probably the *best* thing you can do is refactor your projects so no single directory is 800MB!  But no, I can't think of any reason a "cd" should ever be "expensive".  Either in "git", and/or a shell.

Comment: A plain `cd` wouldn't even look at the contents of the directory. You must have an alias, or a fancy prompt or something doing extra work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you have a git PS1 prompt which might take too much time to display (since a [`git status` in a large repo can be costly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3313908/6309))

[See this gist](https://gist.github.com/bps/883177) for instance, which helps disabling the prompt when you do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

(extract)

```
    local this_git_status=""
    if [ -z "${_skip_git_ps1}" ]; then
        this_git_status=$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")
        case $? in
            0 ) : ;;
            130 ) git_ps1_disable;; # If we break that last command because it's too slow, stop trying it
        esac
    fi
    export PS1=": \u@\h \w${this_git_status}; "
```

Comment: Also check `$PROMPT_COMMAND`

Comment: Many thanks. I do find a PS1 promot in my bash dot file. Seems like there are some cache like things, when I get in the directory again even with the origin dot file, the response time is short.  I will remove it and test it later.