# How does git manage directories

Tags: git

I know git will not see am empty dir but can someone provide a reference to some documentation on how exactly it is implemented.
It's not only about empty folders. If I add a file to a new folder, but I don't add it to the staging area, git actually sees the folder, but not the file.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I know Git will not see an empty dir ...

This is not quite right.  Git will *see* it just fine, it just won't *save* it.

> but can someone provide a reference to some documentation on how exactly it is implemented.

Good software usually tries to hide implementation details, which suggests that Git is not very good, :-) but in this case the implementation details really are pretty well hidden.  Git's internals documentation is [here](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/technical), with one skeleton [api-in-core-index.txt](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/api-in-core-index.txt) last updated 9 years ago (!), and a more recent [index-format.txt](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt).  In any case, tracking is all about Git's *index*, which has several names: "the index", "the staging area", and "the cache".

> It's not only about empty folders. If I add a file to a new folder, but I don't add it to the staging area, Git actually sees the folder, but not the file.

That's not quite right either.  Try running `git status -uall` (or, equivalently, `git status --untracked-files=all`).<sup>1</sup>  What's happening here is that the `git status` command normally *summarizes* the untracked *files* via a simple rule: if a directory named `dir` exists, and some untracked files were found within `dir` but no *tracked* files were found within `dir`, Git just prints `dir/` rather than enumerating each file *within* `dir`.

If you use `-uno` (or `--untracked-files=no`), Git does not even *look for* untracked files, which saves time.  In a large repository (tens of thousands of directories, hundreds of thousands or even millions of files), this can make the difference between `git status` taking well under one second, and `git status` taking many seconds.

Finding *all* untracked files requires comparing the actual work-tree to the cached version of the work-tree stored in the index.  With the normal (summarizing) mode, Git can sometimes use its cache to avoid not only enumerating the files within `dir`, but even *looking inside* `dir`, which also saves time.

Of course, not looking for untracked file at all means Git will never remind you to `git add` such files.  So the default (summarizing) mode is meant as a compromise, both in terms of speed of operation ("If `dir` contains any files<sup>2</sup> in itself or via subdirectories, but we already know no files *within* `dir` are tracked, don't bother doing finer-grained scans for files") and usability ("no need to spam the listing with 19,365 file names within `dir` when we can just say `dir/`").

---

<sup>1</sup>The default if you specify no options is `-unormal`, but if you specify `-u`, that means `-uall`.  You can, however, also set [the `status.showUntrackedFiles` configuration variable](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) to modify the default.

<sup>2</sup>Testing this ("does `dir` or its subdirectories contain any ordinary files") partly depends on support for the `d_type` field in [`readdir`'s](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/readdir.html) [`dirent`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/dirent.h.html) data, which is not required by POSIX but is common (it's certainly found on all modern Unix variants).  Recent versions of Git also have an "untracked cache" extension to the index format, described in [that same technical documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt), that allows Git to skip reading the untracked directories if their `stat` data have not changed, using the `mtime` field of [the `stat` structure](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are two levels to what’s going on: there’s what happens under the hood (plumbing) and what you actually see (porcelain).

To learn all about the plumbing layer, I recommend checking out [this section](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) of Pro Git. In short, a directory is stored as a `tree` object with contents like

```
100644 blob a906cb2a4a904a152e80877d4088654daad0c859      README
100644 blob 8f94139338f9404f26296befa88755fc2598c289      Rakefile
040000 tree 99f1a6d12cb4b6f19c8655fca46c3ecf317074e0      lib
```

The first column is for permissions, the second column is for whether it’s a `blob` (a file) or a `tree` (another directory), the third column is for the SHA-1 of the object, and the last column is the filename.

Although there’s nothing on the plumbing side preventing you from putting an empty `tree` object in a commit, [it can cause problems later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository/8944077#8944077). If you want to achieve a similar effect, you can put a file in the directory. If you want to force the directory to remain empty, you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/932982/27302); if you don’t care if people put files in later, it can be a `README` or an empty `.gitignore`.

Comment: If you *do* manage, via plumbing commands, to put the empty tree (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765453/is-gits-semi-secret-empty-tree-object-reliable-and-why-is-there-not-a-symbolic) into a sub-tree within a commit, Git eventually mishandles it (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8944077/1256452).